# I am getting 404 error for my laravel site

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, vps

I am getting error for my laravel website such as,

**Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to    use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

I have checked my .htaccess file which is in correct way,and I have checked with my hosting server they are saying me that your directory is not redirecting in proper way, Bt previously my site is working properly and suddenly this happen.

So any one have any idea about how to recover from this.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing to set permission for project folder to check whether it correct or not

Comment: I am getting this error:  Starting httpd: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/fabrikaalive/public_htm/public] does not exist

Comment: you had made any change in your public directory